# Making a zoom out/in space map in Unity

Tags: unity, 2d, maps

I'm new to unity, I was wondering how would one go into implementing a dynamic 2d space map. Let me give you an example what i mean. You see our solar system on the map, if you zoom out at a treshold value this solar system would just be represented by a name and our sun and around it you see adjacent solar systems. How would I do this in unity?

Comment: I'll write a demo for you once I get home

Comment: I dont need a demo just a direction to think in since I'm very new to unity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zooming by setting the Z-Position.

Obtain the Z-Position value by using `transform.position.z`, and then make a if-condition to declare when the different modes you would like to show.

```
private float maxZoomIn = 5.0f;
void Update()
{
    zoom();
    checkZoomState();
}

void zoom()
{
    //Simple zooming mechanics
    if(transform.position.z >= maxZoomIn)
        transform.position.z += Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel");
    else
        transform.position.z = maxZoomIn;
}

void checkZoomState()
{
    //Assuming the space map plane is at z = 0
    if(transform.position.z <= maxZoomIn)
        Debug.Log("The camera touches the plane.");
    else if(transform.position.z > maxZoomIn && z <= 50)
        Debug.Log("Zoomed inside the solar system.");
    else if(transform.position.z > 50 && z <= 100)
        Debug.Log("Zoomed outside the solar system, seeing adjacent solar systems");
    //Add more as you like
}
```